# JS file gets a net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, sockets

I am trying to create a simple Io-web-chat.
I recently wanted to seperate my `<script>` inside my html file to an external js file.

**this is my very simple folder structure:**

```
Chat
|-- index.html
|-- index.js
`-- server.js
```

**Relevant part of html file:**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Relevant part of index.js file:**

```
$(function() {

  //Initialize variables
  var $messageArea = $('#messages');
  var $InputMessage = $('#InputMessage');
  var $InputName = $('#InputName');

  //Initialize Socket
  var socket = io();

  //Send server Your message
  socket.emit('chat message', $InputMessage.val());

});
```

**Relevant part of server.js file:**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

I also tried putting my files in this public type structure that they have on the socket.io examples:

```
Chat
|-- Public
|   |-- index.html
|   `-- index.js
`-- server.js
```

in that case I changed:
`src="/index.js"` in html
added `/public/index.html` into the server.js file
But no luck.

This is all running in localhost.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a reverse proxy, like Apache or Nginx? If not, you do not have anything serving an "index.js" file: no reverse proxy, no route, nothing.
Take a look into using express.static() to serve your static files in dev mode, and eventually Nginx later in Production.

Comment: what does "serving index.js file" exactly mean? I don't think I have a proxy, I just run the local host with 'node server'. As you said apache, does this mean I need a dedicated server running at all times when I'm developing? So should I instead use this whole gig on xampp under apache?

Comment: See how you're sending the "index.html" file in your "/" route? Well, your .js file is no exception: you also need to send it in some way. I'll draft up a quick answer that doesn't involve installing Apache or Nginx.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As mentionned in comments: you need a way to send your static files to the client. This can be achieved with a reverse proxy like Nginx, or simply using [express.static()](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Put all your "static" (css, js, images) files in a folder dedicated to it, different from where you put your "views" (html files in your case). I'll call it `static` for the example. Once it's done, add this line in your server code:

```
app.use("/static", express.static('./static/'));
```

This will effectively serve every file in your "static" folder via the /static route.

Querying your index.js file in the client thus becomes:

```
<script src="static/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: So I added 'var express = require('express'); var app = express(); app.use('/static', express.static('./static/')); ' <- into the server.js file As for my folder structure i put the index.js inside the "static" folder and now i am getting "Refused to load the font <url" error, it seems like ive routed it wrong?

Comment: "Cannot GET /" is also displayed on the Dom

Comment: I assumed you were already using express by your notation `app.get("/`, what was "app" referring to in that case if not the express object?

Comment: well i was still using express just in this way -> "var app = require('express')();" as instructed on the socketsio page. 
Plus i noticed the error i mentioned before was "grammarly" my extensions fault.
I disabled it yet I still only get the "cannot GET /" in the DOM error

Comment: Wait but how is it supposed to get to the Html file in the first place?
I rout it to the static folder, yet my html stays untouched. .

Hazaa!! I miss-took your post! i had to "..add this line.." 
Not completely rid the last code i had..
Problem solved!

Comment: @MadWard is it possible to somehow use ```app.use(...express.static())``` twice?  The problem is that my server file index.js is inside a ```functions``` folder since I am using Firebase.Therefore, what I have now is ```app.use(express.static('../../project'));```. Inside ```project``` I have all my folders and files, and it gives me this error with JS. And I have a ```static``` folder with (JS, css, img) and somehow have to use it as well.

Comment: when i tried with edit page its not working.
e.g if i open this url it will get all assets from static http://localhost:8000/edit-category
but if i tried with http://localhost:8000/edit-category/3 then baseurl is changed.
working url ->. http://localhost:8000/public/assets/js/app.js
not working url -> http://localhost:8000/edit-category/public/assets/js/app.js. 
if i add id in last it will not work.
i have also set route like this.
router.get("/edit-category/:id", function (req, res) {
    //code 
}))

Comment: More details -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66854488/public-css-and-js-is-not-loading-while-while-pass-data-from-url

Answer (score 9):

In my case following line gave me the error

```
import { myFunc } from './config'
```

adding file extension to the import solved the issue.

```
import { myFunc } from './config.js'
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue that was resolved by omitting the leading slashes in my code. E.g. replace `/js/script.js` with `js/script.js`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used

```
src="../static/js/controller.js"
```

instead

```
src="/js/controller.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.use("/assets", express.static('./assets/'));
```

Simply replace the static files extension to this. In my case the folder name is `assets` and in it I have `css`, `js`, `images` folders.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the initial slash helped me to solve this error.

replacing the following code

```
/src/index.js
```

with the following code

```
src/index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

For people facing the same problem in Angular 17 you can add in your server.js file "browser" in the path :
[code of server.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLX7w.png)

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;
// const HOST = process.env.HOST;
const app express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(_dirname, "angular", "browser")));
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(_dirname, "angular", "browser", "index.html"));
});
app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log("Server is running on port ${PORT});
});
```

Comment: Please add the code here instead of a link as links become invalid over time. Also add an explanation on how the code helps solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used

```
src="./static/js/controller.js"
```

instead of

```
src="/js/controller.js"
```