# css file is not found

Tags: javascript, webpack

i get a 404 ( net::ERR_ABORTED 404) error when rendering on the github.io. For some reason it’s not seeing the stylesheet.css. localhost works just fine. I moved the link inside the index.html, but it didn’t  help. Any thoughts?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msnya.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94b16.png)

```
{
  "name": "js_project_skeleton",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "skeleton for new JS project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "> 1%",
    "maintained node versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js",
    "webpack:watch": "webpack --watch --config webpack.dev.js",
    "webpack:build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js  --optimize-minimize"
  },
  "author": "mrcjbradley",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "fibers": "^4.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.23.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: is it vue project or anything else, explain details

Comment: js project, just added dependencies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS file gets a net::ERR\_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54173476/js-file-gets-a-neterr-aborted-404-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

try `./src/styles/stylesheet.css` or `src/styles/stylesheet.css`

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to send your static files to the client. This can be achieved with a reverse proxy like Nginx, or simply using `express.static()`.

Put all your "static" (css, js, images) files in a folder dedicated to it, different from where you put your "views" (html files in your case). I'll call it `styles` for the example. Once it's done, add this line in your server code:

```js
app.use("/styles", express.static('./styles/'));
```

This will effectively serve every file in your "styles" folder via the /styles route.

Querying your `stylesheet.css` file in the client thus becomes:

```js
<link href="styles/stylesheet.css">
```

Comment: Was this helpful ?