# JavaScript file net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I would like to add some backend functionality for payment option for my small Firebase web app. My project has the following structure.

```
project 
| functions (cloud functions here)
| --server.js
| static (all JavaScript files for frontend, css, images)
| --style.css
| --index.js
| --images
| index.html
| other HTML files
```

Here is what I have inside my `server.js` file. I am getting `net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` for all my JavaScript files. What should I do here?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('../../project'));
```

I noticed the following two possible posts that might help me, I tried some top answers from there but still stuck, do not actually understand where is the problem and what has to be done.

[JS file gets a net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54173476/js-file-gets-a-neterr-aborted-404-not-found)

[How do I use HTML as the view engine in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911228/how-do-i-use-html-as-the-view-engine-in-express)

Comment: I'd like to understand your project better. Can you please provide your front end file that uses your server.js?

Answer (score 1):

The problem I noticed here is this line `app.use(express.static('../../project'));`
What you are doing is setting the folder `project` to public. Your JS files are inside a static folder, and they do not get read. I would suggest the following structure:

```
project 
  server.js
  static (folder)
    HTML (folder for all HTML files)
    css (folder for all css files)
    js (folder for all js files)
```

Then in your `server.js` file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('./static'));
```