# Public css and js is not loading while while pass data from url

Tags: node.js, express

## working url

-> http://localhost:8000/edit-category

-> http://localhost:8000/public/assets/images/users/avatar-1.jpg

## not working url

-> http://localhost:8000/edit-category/12

-> http://localhost:8000/edit-category/public/assets/images/users/avatar-1.jpg

if i remove edit-category from url then all css and js will render

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this problem in node with express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<BaseUrl />` tag in head.
this will solve the problem